# Alter Exposed filter form

Tags: views, forms, taxonomy-terms

I would like to know how to get parent terms only, for example "Ages 0-2" and also print in dropdown.

This is the structure of the form array.

```
Array(
  [#info] => Array(
    [filter-tid] => Array(
      [operator] => tid_op
      [value] => tid
      [label] => Term
      [description] => 
    )
  )
  [tid] => Array(
    [#type] => select
    [#options] => Array(
      [All] => - Any -
      [0] => stdClass Object(
        [option] => Array(
          [367] => Ages 0-2
        )
      )
      [1] => stdClass Object(
        [option] => Array(
          [2378] => -Infant
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

This is the code I am using.

```
  if ($form['#id']== "views-exposed-form-quick-find") { 
    $test = $form['tid']['#options'];
    foreach ($test as $tid) {
      // It prints "Array" and the "Trying to get property of non-object" message.
      print $tid->option;
    }
  }
```

I do not understand why the "Array" text repeats; it could be I am not pointing to right array.

How do I remove all children which do not have "age 12 - 14" (see "-" in the middle not from start)?

Comment: Hello, and welcome on Drupal Answers. May you show more of the code you are using? In particular, which function/hook contains that code?

Answer (score 0):

What you obtain from that code is exactly what you should obtain.

The values you are getting from that control statement are:

- `$form['tid']['#options']['All']` is a string, and not an object. Trying to access `$form['tid']['#options']['All']->option` gives you a warning about accessing a property for something that is not an object.
- `$form['tid']['#options'][0]` is an object, and it doesn't raise an error, but `$form['tid']['#options'][0]->option` is an array, and `print $form['tid']['#options'][0]->option` converts it in a string. That is why you see *Array*.
- The same is true for `$form['tid']['#options'][1]`.

To remove the array element that contains `'Age 12 - 14'` from `$form['tid']['#options']`, I would use the following code.

```
foreach ($form['tid']['#options'] as $index => $tid) {
  if (is_object($tid) && !empty($tid->option) && is_array($tid->option) && in_array('Ages 12-14', $tid->option)) {
    unset($form['tid']['#options'][$index]);
  }
}
```

Notice that `in_array()` is case-sensitive. If you are searching for `'Age 12 - 14'`, but the string is `'age 12 - 14'`, the code doesn't remove the option.